# Books on Android packages?

Tags: android

Is there any good books which explains all the packages and in-built classes in Android SDK? There are few good books, but it does not explains all the packages available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why dont you try

https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

and

https://developer.android.com/reference/classes.html.

No book can explain android packages and classes better than this

Please download **Documentation for Android SDK** from **Android SDK Manager** to get offline access to these packages and classes